# Jquery dynamically update "other" option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm working on a project that will be using a lot of select menus to enter various data. I'd like to include an 'other' option directly in the select that will trigger a simple dialog and allow users to enter a custom value (where appropriate) similar to the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function chkother(fld,len,idx) {
        if ((idx+1)==len) {
            other=prompt("Please indicate 'other' value:");
            fld.options[idx].value=other;
            fld.options[idx].text=other;
        }
    }
</script>
```

which works with a select:

```
<select onchange="chkother(this,this.options.length,this.options.selectedIndex)" name="example" id="example" class="formSelect">
<option  value=""></option>
<option  value="yes">yes</option>
<option  value="no">no</option>
<option  value="other">other</option>
</select>
```

And brings up a prompt that will update the option with the users text.

I'd like to do something similar using jquery so I can look at extending the functionality and learning a bit of jquery, but I'm having trouble getting started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will get you started.  This will add the functionality to any select on the page, appending a new value to the select (and leaving other still available in case a mistake has been made).

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change( function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (!value || value == '') {
           var other = prompt( "Please indicate other value:" );
           if (!other) return false;
           $(this).append('<option value="'
                             + other
                             + '" selected="selected">'
                             + other
                             + '</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @tvanfosson the solution looks terrific but when I add it to my page nothing happens. If I understand it right (and I don't understand javascript or jquery well) it searches all the selects for either missing values or empty values ("") and will replace the value via prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I must have made a mistake. The function works great, thanks so much!

Comment: The way it works is when a select changes, it checks the new value.  If it is empty, then it prompts (as in your previous solution) for a new value and constructs a selected option from the value and appends it to the select that was changed.

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved a problem very similar to this and ended up writing a jQuery plugin ([jQuery.otherDropdown](http://otherdropdown.code.jstassen.com)) to collect an 'other' response for a select dropdown. It's on [GitHub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.otherdropdown) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.otherdropdown). I'll break down my approach so you can implement it your own way.

This idea is a perfect use case for jQuery in my opinion.

## The basic components

### Listen for when your 'other' options is slected

Add a `.change()` event binding on the select input.

```
$('select').change( function() {
    if(this.value === 'other') {
        // Your logic here to for when/how to prompt for user input
    }
});
```

### Listen for user input

If you choose an text input instead of a prompt (which may be a better user experience), listen for the blur event

```
// listen to a text area
$('input').blur( function() {
    if(this.value !== '') {
        // Logic to add the new option to the select
    }
});

// or bring up a prompt dialog
var value=prompt("Please indicate 'other' value:");
if(this.value !== '') {
    // Logic to add the new option to the select
}
```

### Add the new option

No matter how you choose to prompt the user for the value, adding it is as simple as creating the element via jQuery and appending it. Lastly you'll probably want to focus the value, which can be done with `.val()`

```
var $option = $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
$('select').append($option);
$('select').val(value);
```

### Example

All of these ideas are wrapped in this plugin and might a good example you can play with and reuse to work how you need. You can see it working [here](http://otherdropdown.code.jstassen.com)

```
/**
 * @name jquery.otherdropdown
 * @description A small jQuery plugin to support a text area when selecting an 'Other' option in a dropdown
 * @version 1.0.2
 * @author Jonathan Stassen <jstassen.com>
 * @see https://github.com/TheBox193/jquery.otherdropdown
 */
$.fn.otherDropdown = function(options) {
    var $this = this;
    // Allow a different name/value to trigger, default to 'other'
    var opts = $.extend({}, {value: 'other'}, options);
    opts.name_lower = opts.value.toLowerCase();
    opts.name_upper = opts.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opts.value.slice(1);
    opts.placeholder = opts.placeholder || opts.name_upper;

    // Bind to all change events
    $this.change( function(ev){

        // Swap in the text area if our 'other' option was chosen
        if (this.value === opts.name_lower || this.value === opts.name_upper) {
            $this.hide().after( $textInput );
            $textInput.focus();
        }
    });

    // Prepare our text input
    var $textInput = $('<input type="text" class="otherdropdown" placeholder="' + opts.placeholder + '" />');

    // Allow custom classes on the text input
    if (opts.classes) {
        $textInput.addClass(opts.classes);
    }

    // Bind to blur to swap back to select dropdown
    $textInput.blur( function(ev) {
        var value = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.remove();
        $this.show();

        if (value === '' || value === opts.name_lower || value === opts.name_upper) {
            return;
        }

        // If something was typed, create a new option with that value
        var $searchedOption = $this.children('[value="' + value + '"]');

        // If value doesn't exist, added it.
        if ( $searchedOption.length < 1 ) {
            var $option = $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
            $this.append($option);
        }

        // Focus the value
        $this.val( value );
    });
};
```