# How to make a popup from unlisted option form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new in JavaScript and need help.

I am making a Real Estate Website. In POST NEW PROPERTY page, I have a select form that will show States from the following Country select form.

```
<select>
     <option value="1">United State</option>
      <option value="2">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="3">Singapore</option>
      <option value="4">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```

When people don't find his country from the above form, I need my website to show a popup containing  an input form and the visitor could add new country and save it to database as additional country list in the future. The form would be like this :

```
 <select>
      <option value="1">United State</option>
      <option value="2">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="3">Singapore</option>
      <option value="4">Indonesia</option>
      <option value="others" OnClick="ShowInputPopup();">Add your country</option>
    </select>
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15506601/3444240

Comment: Option elements can't contain other HTML elements. Just "normal character data" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data)