# save selected options [<select> values in database

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to save selected options  values in database . In form, I need to include **select options** inside **input type** , Basically i have this code.

```
<form method="post">
    <td>Designer order number </td>
    <td>
        <div id="ordernumbers">
            <select>
                <option>Select Order</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <input type="text" name="dueDate" value=""/>
    <input name="register1" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Update" 
onclick="return updatepayment(); "/>
</form>
```

[image]

To include select option inside form , i tried as [link1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_form) but did't worked for me.

than [i followed below code as in mentioned in link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506601/how-to-input-text-in-html-select-tag)

```
<form>
    <td>
        <div id="ordernumbers">
            <input type="text" name="designerorder_id" list="citynames">
            <datalist id="citynames">
                <option>Select Order</option>
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </td>
</form>
```

still i am getting `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id` error , but instead of above code , if i use this code : `<input type="text"  name="designerorder_id"  />` i am not getting any error, so i guess i am doing in mistake in putting select inside input in form, please help me for this....

**EDit**

```
if (isset($_POST['register1'])) {

  $designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);
  $product_id = trim($_POST['product_id']);
  $paid_status = password_hash($_POST['paid_status'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $due_date = trim($_POST['due_date']);

  $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt->execute();


    if ($reg_user->register1($designerorder_id, $product_id, $paid_status, $due_date)) {
      $id = $reg_user->lasdID();
      $key = base64_encode($id);
      $id = $key;

      $message = " updated database";

   //   $subject = "Confirm updation";

    //  $reg_user->send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
      $msg = "database updated ";

    } else {
      echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
    }
  }
```

Note : i am requesting downvoter, please inform in comments reason for downvote so that i can correct it....

Comment: you are giving us a php error but havent provided any php

Comment: My guess, you are trying to use `$_POST['designerorder_id']`.. post your PHP so we dont have to guess.

Comment: @atoms i wanted to know how we can include `select` inside `input types` in forms..... i removed `php` tag..... i guess mostly its error with html....

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id` is a PHP error, no?

Comment: @chris85 you are right, thats php error , but when i include this code instead of `select code`, i am not getting any error : `<input type="text"  name="designerorder_id"  />` so i thought its not php error.....

Comment: please tell why downvotes, i really tried lot before asking question.....

Comment: `<form>` is not going to send a `POST`, you need to have the `method` attribute. That's the cause of your error message. Provide one code block you are having issues and explain exactly what you are trying to do. `input`s dont have `select`/`options`. A `select` has `option`s.

Comment: @chris85 i updated question with php code.... all i wanted to know is i can able to do `<input type= "text">` , but i have `select` , i dont know how to  include under `input` ....

Comment: `select`s can't have `input`s. They have `option`s. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @chris85 i want to save selected value in database , how i can do that, please help me.....

Comment: @atoms i updated question with php code......

Comment: just before `if (isset($_POST['register1']))` do `var_dump($_POST)`;  Could you update your answer with the result of that please? AND ensure form tag has the post method property assigned `<form method='post'>`

Comment: @atoms `array(0) { }` is result......

Comment: so thats telling you the $_POST data isnt making it to the page. This could be form numerous reasons. You might be overwriting the data, or might not be sending a post request. I suggest you enure your form tag looks like this `<form action='/path/to/script.php' method='post'>`. Then using a network inspector tool ensure the fields are being send as post. Let me know when you are seeing results in `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: when i try : `<input type="text" name="designerorder_id" />` , its giving result : `array(3) { ["designerorder_id"]=> string(4)` , but when i tried the code i posted in question, its not giving any values, you can see complete code here : http://pastebin.com/8rCwmNPH @atoms

Comment: does it work if you change the select tag to: `<select onchange="getOrderDetail(event);" name='designerorder_id'>` and ensuring the forms markup is as I've described. Input data needs a name or it doesnt get posted

Comment: @atoms i changed select tag as you said, still its giving error as `Notice: Undefined index: designerorder_id in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/posting.php on line` in line `$designerorder_id = trim($_POST['designerorder_id']);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128373/discussion-between-atoms-and-abcd).